# expectation of a random variable conditional on the max of another two random variables

Tags: probability-theory

I have one question for help. $(C,X,Y)$ are continuous random variables, $(C,Y)$ is independent of $X$, $Z=\max(X,Y)$, how to calculate $E[C|Z=b]$? I want to calculate this in terms of the sum of two cases, one is $E[C|X=b,Y\le b]$, the other one is $E[C|X\le b,Y=b]$, and probably each one times their conditional probability. Could someone help me? Thanks a lot.:)

If it was the discrete case, then let $A,A_1,A_2$ be events such that $A=A_1\cup A_2$ and $A_1\cap A_2=\emptyset$, then for any random variable $X$, we have 
$$\text{E}[X|A]=\text{E}[X|A_1]\frac{P(A_1)}{P(A_1)+P(A_2)}+\text{E}[X|A_2]\frac{P(A_2)}{P(A_1)+P(A_2)}$$
But my question is about the continuous case, considering $(C,X,Y)$, where $X,Y$ are independent, my original thinking is that
\begin{align*}
\text{E}[C|Z=b]&=\text{E}[C|X\le b,Y=b]\frac{P(X\le b,Y=b)}{P(Z=b)}
+\text{E}[C|X=b,Y\le b]\frac{P(X=b,Y\le b)}{P(Z=b)}\\
&=\text{E}[C|X\le b,Y=b]\frac{P(X\le b)P(Y=b)}{P(Z=b)}
+\text{E}[C|X=b,Y\le b]\frac{P(X=b)P(Y\le b)}{P(Z=b)}
\end{align*}
Now the problem is that $X,Y,Z$ are all continuous, so the probability of a continuous random variable at a single point is $0$, I feel that in the continuous case, the conditional expectation can be decomposed in terms of density, but I am not sure about how to write this specifically, and I do not know if simply replacing any zero probability with density is the right way to go.

Comment: Are these continuous or discrete variables?

Comment: Hi, Berci, they are continuous variables.

Comment: Ok. Then it's similar.. : ) Just write integral instead of sum...

Comment: I understand your way of calculation. But the continuous case is not so straight forward since some conditional probability will be zero due to the continuous property. Could you see my updated version of question in which I am more specific. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes. Thank you for updating. I may turn back to this question later and will edit my answer.

Comment: Do you have some kind of independence? Are you working with specific random variables?.

Comment: Hi, Bunder, I forgot to mention that $(C,Y)\perp X$, I just added this condition.

Comment: But I am not working with any specific random variables

Comment: Got something from an answer below?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, your intuition stemming from the discrete case is correct since
$$
E[C\mid Z=b]=p(b)\cdot E[C\mid X=b,Y\leqslant b]+(1-p(b))\cdot E[C\mid Y=b,X\leqslant b],
$$
where
$$
p(b)=P[X=b\mid Z=b]=\frac{f_X(b)F_Y(b)}{f_X(b)F_Y(b)+f_Y(b)F_X(b)}.
$$
To justify this formula, going back to the definitions is enough... depending on how you define conditional expectations for continuous random variables. :-)